# Prove that the property of being bipartite for a graph is recognizable.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that the property of being bipartite for a graph is recognizable.

> **Definition**: A graphical parameter or graphical property is **recognizable** if for each graph $G$ of order at elast 3, it's possible to determine the value of the parameter for $G$ or whether $G$ has the property from the subgraph $G-v$, $v\in V(G)$

I'm not sure I understand the definition very well.

I know that bipartite graph doesn't contain odd cycle. I also know that for any bipartite graph of order $n$, then $m\leq \frac {n^2}{4}$.

Are these property enough to say the order and size of a bipartite are recognizable parameter?

> **Theorem 5.7**: If $G$ is a graph of order $n \geq 3$ then $n$ and $m$ as well as degree of vertices of $G$ are determined from the $n$ subgraphs $G-v$, $v\in V(G)$

the book tells me from theorem 5.7, I can say that for the graph of order at least 3, the order, size and degree of its vertices are recognizable parameters. It also follow that the property of regular graph is recognizable because the degree of regularity is recognizable parameter.

For bipartite graph I think one of the property that is recognizable is you can color every vertex of  the same part with the same color because they are not adjacent to each other, so every bipartite has at most 2 different color, right?

Comment: This definition seems to imply that you are given single subgraph $G-v$. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture#Recognizable_properties), we are given *every* subgraph $G-v$, $\forall v \in \operatorname{V}(G)$. So then the problem could be restated as "if I give you every subgraph $G-v$, can you tell me if $G$ is bipartite?"

Comment: yes, if you give me all of the subgraph $G-v$, I can find the order, size, and degree of each vertex in $G$, from that I maybe able to check that $G$ doesn't have any odd cycle, thus it's bipartite, right?

Comment: It might help if you added some properties that you already know are recognizable. For example, it is known that the chromatic polynomial is recognizable. If you know this (from class for example), then your question is trivial since you can then just plug in $x=2$ and check if you get out zero or not.

Comment: odd cycle is example that chromatic number is not recognizable property. Generally - G-v should have property A and from this the property B of G should follow. A and B are not required to be the same properties to prove that B is rezognizable property. Simply, some property A should exist.